# [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have already asked this question already(closed due to inactivity) and I have been trying many different methods to solve it but it still doesn't work. I even try removing all those related to vue inside laravel by following many different kind of website where they all told me to remove the vue dependency. (here is one of the link that I followed, https://mattstauffer.com/blog/removing-all-vue-dependencies-from-laravel/) I even replaced the app.js with a new one created from scratch since in the past I didn't do anything to it

Can somebody please help me, I am stuck in this problem for quite a long time already and I really don't know what to do. All I want is to solve this error `"[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:"` since it is affecting the navbar in my webpage

I am using laravel framework 5.5.7 and I didn't even update my laravel to get until this vue. And also I don't even recall installing vue into my laravel.

```
This is the error they given me:
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.


(found in <Root>)
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">


                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
<html>
<head>
              <title>SideBar Menu</title>
     <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="sidebar">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{route('home')}}">Summary</a></li>        
            <li><a href="{{route('deleted_result')}}">Deleted Records</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Edit User Information <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url('/edit') }}" style="color: red">Personal Information Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('/edit0')}}" style="color: red">Driver License Class Edit</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Evaluation <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
             <li><a href="{{ url('/edit8')}}" style="color: red">Evaluation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        </ul>

        <div id="sidebar-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}" style="color: white">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>
                    <div id="center-text">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" id="nav-center">
                            <li>
                                <h3>@yield('title')</h3>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color:blue" style="color:white">
                                    <b>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: blue">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="background-color: blue" style="color: white">
                                            <b>Logout</b>
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developer tool error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218763/developer-tool-error)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the question you have already asked without going any more into depth simply for the sake of drawing more attention to your previous question. Please update your previous question by reformatting, posting code examples from Github, etc. Voting to close this for now.

Comment: @Stephan-v In my previous question, I did asked it but I did try different method to do it but it still doesn't work, I will edit this question here and also close the previously asked question to prevent duplication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158841/discussion-between-dkna-and-samayo).